# Extending Core.Option module in F#

Tags: f#

I want to extend one of the existing "core" modules, like `Core.Option`:

```
module Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Option

    let filter predicate op =
        match op with
        | Some(v) -> if predicate(v) then Some(v) else None
        | None -> None
```

(I know about `bind` function, but I think `filter` method for options in some case is more convenient).

But unfortunetely I can't use `filter` method without explicitely open `Microsoft.FSharp.Core` namespace:

```
// Commenting following line will break the code!
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core

let v1 = Some 42
let v2 = v1 |> Option.filter (fun v -> v > 40)

printfn "v2 is: %A" v2
```

In most cases we can't use functions from module without opening appropriate namespace. 
F# compiler "opens" some predefine (core) namespace automatically (like `Microsoft.FSharp.Core`), this will not bring into the scope methods from "module extensions" and we still should open core namespaces manually.

**My question is: Is there any workarounds?**

Or the best way to extend "core" modules is to create such extensions in custom namespace and open this namespace manually?

```
// Lets custom Option module in our custom namespace
module CustomNamespace.Option

    let filter predicate op = ...

// On the client side lets open our custom namespace.
// After that we can use both Option modules simultaneously!
open CustomNamespace

let v1 = Some 42
let b = 
    v1 |> Option.filter (fun v -> v > 40) // using CustomNamespace.Option
    |> Option.isSome // using Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Option
```

Comment: there is no need for custom namespaces

Comment: I have a ton of examples of this -- including the exact function you want -- in my GitHub: https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/Pervasive.fs

Answer (score 8):

For production code I would do what the Taha's answer suggests: create your own module and open/alias it as necessary. Most of your life as programmer will be spent reading code. It can be quite frustrating reading F# code where it is not clear where methods come from.

That being said, I was surprised to find that this works:

```
namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Core

module Option =

    let filter predicate op =
        match op with
        | Some(v) -> if predicate(v) then Some(v) else None
        | None -> None

namespace USERCODE

module Option = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Option

module M =

    let test () =
        Some 1
        |> Option.filter (fun x -> x > 0)
        |> Option.map (fun x -> x + 1)
```

It does not remove the need to write something in the head of your files, but it does work around needing to open a namespace. Not relevant for `Microsoft.FSharp.Core` as it is always open by default, but helpful for other namespaces.

Answer (score 6):

In order to extend an F# module create another with the same name:

```
module Option =

    let filter predicate op =
        match op with
        | Some v  -> match predicate v with true -> Some v | false -> None
        | None    -> None


let v1 = Some 42
let v2 = v1 |> Option.filter (fun v -> v > 40)

printfn "v2 is: %A" v2
```

Comment: So you create Option module in the global namespace. Thats OK, but I don't think that this is appropriate solution for production code.

Comment: You don't have to do it in the global namespace, as long as you `open` the containing namespace. That's how it's done.

Comment: And you can put several extension modules in the same namespace. This is even better, as this allows control over the extension modules (and doesn't just pop them up automatically).

Answer (score 5):

Does it help if you add the AutoOpen attribute to the module?

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Option

    let filter predicate op =
        match op with
        | Some(v) -> if predicate(v) then Some(v) else None
        | None -> None
```

*EDIT*

This works, but only across assembly borders. It doesn't work within the same assembly:

```
namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Core
module Option =
    let filter predicate op =
        match op with
        | Some(v) -> if predicate(v) then Some(v) else None
        | None -> None

[<assembly:AutoOpen("Microsoft.FSharp.Core")>]
do ()
```

To call it from another assembly:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    let f () = Some "" |> Option.filter (fun f -> true)
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
    0
```

Comment: No, I tried this first. This won't help. Because AutoOpen attribute applies to module itself but not to modules namespace.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I tried to use AutoOpen attribute on the declared module.

Comment: It seems that this solution is not working if extension resides in the same assembly.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov Yup. That's why I said so in the answer. :)

Comment: thanks. Anyway this is really good solution. For example, it will work perfectly for some reusable library!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions) something like this should work in extending a type.  However I must have got something wrong as it won't compile and gives. the following error:

> One or more of the declared type parameters for this type extension
>   have a missing or wrong type constraint not matching the original type
>   constraints on 'Option<_>'F# Compiler(957)

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type Option with
    [<Extension>]
    static member fromBool predicate word =
        if predicate word
        then Some word
        else None
```

This isn't a functioning answer more an addendum to the original question.  Not sure if it is worth opening a new thread?